# Decide when to load html file

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem I am encountering is that I want to be able to view the `row` variable without the waiting for event click.

**Works:** JQuery event waiting for click, row is view-able:

```
$('[data-row]').on('click', function() {
   var row = $(this).attr('data-row');
    alert(row); // 
});
```

**Does not work:** This is what I want to work...?:

```
$('[data-row]').(function() {
   var row = $(this).attr('data-row');
    alert(row); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `each`

```
$('[data-row]').each(function() {
   var row = $(this).attr('data-row');
   alert(row); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unclear. What does alert($row) have to do with deciding to load an HTML file?

You could use setTimeout function to avoid clicking.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the line 1 and 4 of your 2nd code.
This must be inside of jquery document.ready
Your code must be like this

```
var row = $(this).attr('data-row');
alert(row);
```